# How to check two conditions in an IF statement in windows phone 7 application using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application for windows phone 7 where i have a form and i need to validate two conditions here. The condition is that the textbox shouldnot contain null value and also the value should not be equal to *Name.

```
if(name.Text == String.Empty)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
   name.Focus();
   return false;
}
```

Please help me to put the 2nd condition here

Comment: I'm not sure but `if((name.Text != null) && (name.Text != "Name"))` ? What do you mean by `*Name` ? Is it a different variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((name.Text == String.Empty) || (name.Text == "Name"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how to check a field like phone number so that it contains only numbers and also how to check the email field

Comment: You can use regular expressions in order to validate the text as number and emails.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `&&` operator, something like this

```
        if (name.Text == String.Empty && name.Text != *Name)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `name.Text != *Name` should be `name.Text != "*Name"`

Comment: Wasn't quite sure what OP meant by *Name

Comment: @JAnderson Actually i have placed it like a placeholder

Answer (score 3):

you need OR condition like below

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Text) || name.Text == "Name")
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
     name.Focus();
     return false;

}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to exactly opposite what you write. **The condition is that the textbox should not contain null value and also the value should not be equal to Name** In your case, if `name.Text` is `"Name"`, you _if statement_ will work but OP doesn't want that as far as I understand.

Comment: This is so weird. Accepted answer do the opposite thing exactly what OP wants (like your answer) but still accepted. This is unbelievable.

Comment: @SonerGönül what do u mean by OP?

Comment: @bhaku It means "Original Poster", the person asking the question. In this case, it is you. Take a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Answer (score 2):

```
if (name.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
            return false;
        }
else
        {
            if(name.Text == "Name"){

                 MessageBox.Show("Your error message");
                 name.Focus();
                 return false;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if (name.Text == null && name.Text != "Name")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
        name.Focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((name.Text == String.Empty) || (name.Text == "Name"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
            return false;
        }
```